# structure for displaying and manipulating JSON - week and reservation times

Tags: json, reactjs, list, calendar

i'm making dummy reservation system in react, i need to create JSON file which for example will contain 5 days, each containing 5 reservation times like 9:00 , 10:00 etc.  What is the best approach to not only creating it, but manipulating it easily, i will place it in the state and display it like a list/calendar, which i can manipulate.
at the moment i have :

```
[
 {
  "2019-02-04":{
    "10:00":{ reserved:true, name:"johny" },
    "11:00":{ reserved:false, name:"johny"}
 },
  "2019-02-05":{
    "10:00":{ reserved:true, name:"johny" },
    "11:00":{ reserved:false, name:"johny"}
}
]
```

but i doubt it is a good solution ?  or something like that.

```
    [
     {
        "date":"2019-02-04",
        "10:00":{ reserved:true, name:"johny" },
        "11:00":{ reserved:false, name:"johny"}
     },
      {
        "date":"2019-02-05",
        "10:00":{ reserved:true, name:"johny" },
        "11:00":{ reserved:false, name:"johny"}
    }
    ]
```